# Troggle class on viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport, window-resize

I have my navigation. When I reach viewport < 860px the class `<nav class="nav"` needs to be `<nav class="nav-mobile"`
I came pritty far but really need to get rid of the ``class="nav". Below script only ADDS the nav-mobile but doesn't remove class="nav".

```
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-mobile', $(window).width() < 860);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery solution**

```
function appResize()
{
   if($(window).width() < 860){
        $('nav').addClass("nav-mobile");
        $('nav').removeClass("nav");
      }
      else{
        $('nav').removeClass("nav-mobile");
        $('nav').addClass("nav");
      }
}

$(function(){
appResize();
})

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  appResize();
});
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/7fs7xrma/1/

**CSS3 solution** use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

html

```
<nav class="nav"></nav>
```

css

```
.nav{
     background:red; 
     height:20px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width : 860px){
.nav{
    background:blue;
    }
}
```

demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7fs7xrma/2/

Comment: actually, I need to have class="nav" when no js is used. But when I add class="nav" and I look at the site on a mobile the .nav class is still there, only when resizing the mobile class is added. Do you know how to do this? maybe window on resize needs to be different?

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions `addClass` and `removeClass`.

```
function setSize(){
  if($(window).width() < 860){
    $('.nav').addClass("nav-mobile");
    $('.nav-mobile').removeClass("nav");
  }
  else{
    $('.nav-mobile').addClass("nav");
    $('.nav').removeClass("nav-mobile");
  }

}
$(document).ready(function () {
  setSize();
});
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  setSize();
});
```

However, for graceful degradation of your website, you should use CSS3 media queries for browsers that disable jS for security reasons. Consider reading an article on how to make a site [responsive](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en).

Comment: hmm well I really need to remove the nav class because I have so many styles onto it, its a very custom navigation. thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake. Problem corrected. Refresh the page.

Comment: i see you changed "this" to "body". now it works. But I need onload AND on resize I guess.